# Vagrant / Clojure / Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, vagrant

I want to put together a standard environment for exploring Clojure with Emacs. Has anyone got a recipe that would suit this? I'm thinking of a Vagrant system running a flavour of Ubuntu, with NREPL and some useful EMACS support plugins.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Check out [Clojure for the brave and true guide](http://www.braveclojure.com/). The guy created a setup for Emacs which is just awesome. You get everything packed together and ready to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Github hosted, shell provisioned vagrant setup is located here:

https://github.com/pattinsont/Ukelele

All that should be required is a checkout and vagrant up.

Once the VM is up, ssh onto box.
Run emacs to complete install.
Then M-x cider-jack-in

Answer (score 11):

```
vagrant box add preciseMinimal http://goo.gl/wxdwM
```

Change to Clojure vagrant base folder

```
vagrant init preciseMinimal
vagrant up

vagrant ssh
```

or ssh to 127.0.0.1 port 2222 (or other port mentioned in "vagrant up" output)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cassou/emacs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs24 emacs24-el emacs24-common-non-dfsg
sudo apt-get install clojure

cd ~/
mkdir bin

sed '$ a\
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH' ~/.bashrc
```

exit and reconnect to ssh

```
cd ~/bin
wget https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/preview/bin/lein
chmod +x lein
./lein


cd ~
cat >.emacs
; Package.el customization
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

;; install packages
(defvar my-packages '(
  auto-complete
  clojure-mode
  clojure-test-mode
  nrepl
  ac-nrepl
  paredit
  rainbow-delimiters
))

(dolist (p my-packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
  (package-refresh-contents)
    (package-install p)))
;; The following line can be removed after first install to speed up startup
(byte-recompile-directory (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d") 0)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(auto-save-default nil)
 '(backup-inhibited t t)
 '(cursor-type 'bar t)
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(delete-selection-mode t)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(initial-scratch-message nil)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil)
 '(xterm-mouse-mode 1))

;; rainbow delimiters
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)

;; paredit
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(global-set-key [f7] 'paredit-mode)

;; clojure-mode
(global-set-key [f9] 'nrepl-jack-in)

;; nrepl
(add-hook 'nrepl-interaction-mode-hook 'nrepl-turn-on-eldoc-mode)
(setq nrepl-popup-stacktraces nil)
(add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*nrepl*")
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)

;; Auto complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(define-key ac-completing-map "\M-/" 'ac-stop)

;; ac-nrepl
(require 'ac-nrepl)
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'nrepl-interaction-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(eval-after-load "auto-complete" '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'nrepl-mode))
#CTRL-D to finish
```

Grateful attributions:
http://blog.worldcognition.com/2012/07/setting-up-emacs-for-clojure-programming.html

Comment: `paredit` may be slightly jarring for new Emacs users.  If you stick with it, your future self will be ever grateful.

Comment: Is it possible to use Chef to install the packages and maybe upload the .emacs?

Comment: A fun project would be to package all this up in a Vagrant / puppet config so that e.g. checkout from GitHub and 'vagrant up' would be all that would be needed.

Comment: see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/seajure/vagrant/seajure/6yWemZ04HV0/hFp9LFz-Q3MJ

Comment: @event_jr I started this project to provide a base to learn Clojure, specifically on the emacs platform. I'll take your advice on paredit.

Comment: @mac - I've put a shell provisioned Vagrantfile on github. I'll leave a chef version for the more ambitious. As a matter of curiosity, what would that provide this type of build over a script?

Comment: @johnj what would you see the advantage of a puppet config be over a chef or script provisioned vagrant setup?

Comment: Thanks @georgek - It was quite out of date but I used a lot of the ideas behind the seajure setup. All the good ideas were from there, all of the clunkiness was mine.

Comment: @Terry I think Chef could work fine as well; the main idea is that one could just do `git clone xxx; cd xxx; vagrant up; vagrant ssh` and be ready to go.

Comment: I don't have a strong preference for Chef over shell script, although it is my understanding that Chef recipies might be a bit more robust and maintainable.

Comment: @Terry check my comment on the question.

Comment: How would you connect if emacs was installed in the host instead of vagrant ? If I do `M-x cider-connect` `vagrant@ip`, port `59358` type password, I get an error (because there is no nrepl running).