# How to Install Clojure 1.5 on Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, clojure

I am a clojure beginner.

I try to search for  clojure 1.5 installation methods on Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

but I did not find.

If anyone knows, please answer me,

If there step by step Installation Steps or photo, is best

Thank you.

Comment: Re-post this question on Ask Ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 6):

Clojure is not a standalone program; instead, it is used like a library, added as a dependency to each Clojure project. Thus, you do not install Clojure, but rather a build tool capable of managing dependencies.

The most popular such build tool in the Clojure community is [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/); follow the link for installation instructions. (There is a Debian package for Leiningen and you could install it with `aptitude` / `apt-get`, but it's quite outdated at this time. Happily, manual installation involves a single command.) Once you've got it installed, do the following in a terminal:

```
$ lein new app hello-world
$ cd hello-world
$ lein run
Hello, World!
```

The last line is what you should see with the current version of the app template. Looking around the `hello-world` directory will give you an idea of how a basic Clojure project is structured. Also, Leiningen's documentation is very good, you should definitely at least skim it.

Apart from Leiningen, there's [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), which will be familiar to any Java developer, and a Clojure plugin for [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) -- [clojuresque](https://bitbucket.org/clojuresque/clojuresque).

All these share the Maven infrastructure, so you'll have access to the entire ecosystem of Clojure (and Java) libraries regardless of which one you pick.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete setup, including a functional emacs, leiningen and ubuntu, all hosted in a convenient Vagrant setup, see:
[Vagrant / Clojure / Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872231/vagrant-clojure-emacs/16872232#16872232)