# connect emacs cider to vagrant host clojure project

Tags: emacs, ssh, clojure, vagrant, cider

I am trying to use `vagrant`, `Clojure` and `emacs` together. Specifically, I can't connect `cider` to my `vagrant` machine.

It works locally, when I run `cider-jack-in` inside my project.
But I don't know what are the steps to do that inside the same project (synced via vagrant shared folders) on the vagrant machine.

Here is my attempt so far :

- `ssh vagrant`, then `cd my-project-dir`, then `lein repl`
- in emacs, `cider-connect`, input `vagrant@192.168.50.50`, port `22`

I get the following message :

> SSH port forwarding failed. check the *nrepl-tunnel* buffer.

Inside that buffer :

> OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011 Privileged ports can only be
>   forwarded by root.
>
> Process nrepl-tunnel exited abnormally with code 255

Ho do I run that as root ? Is it really the problem ? Should I use another port ? Do I have to put something specific in my Clojure code to enable that ? The directions given [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#connect-to-a-running-nrepl-server) are a bit unclear to me.

**Note** : it differs from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872231/vagrant-clojure-emacs) because `emacs` runs on the host machine, not on the `vagrant` machine

**Edit** :

Here are the detailed steps I did, thanks to @Shlomi's answer :

- Edit .ssh/config by adding the following (edit IP according to you `Vagrantfile`) :

  Host vagrant
      HostName 192.168.50.50
      Port 22
      User vagrant
      ForwardAgent yes
- in the host, start my project with `lein repl`. Pay attention to the port in the message : `nREPL server started on port 42018 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:42018`
- in emacs, `M-x cider-connect`, input vagrant, your password and the port noted by the previous `lein` command.
- That's it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the port you are using is the ssh port instead of the nrepl port.

The way I usually use emacs for remote access is through tramp:

1. [Add an entry in .ssh/config](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) for your remote host, say *vagrant*
2. In emacs, `cider-connect`, input `vagrant`
3. In recent versions of cider, it will automatically find all active nrepl sessions on that host, and show their project name and port, so select the right one, and you should be able to start working.

Comment: 3. Doesn't work straight away, or I haven't properly started a nrepl on the vagrant machine ? I get asked A - my password B - a port to connect (I tried 59258) C - My password again ("In buffer *nrepl-tunnel*) vagrant@192.168.50.50's password") D - the connection is closed ("nREPL, Connection unexpectedly closed ...").

Comment: Oh I had to pay attention to the message in the nRepl : "nREPL server started on port 42018 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:42018". Now it works thanks (+1).

Comment: You should also check `ssh-copy-id`, this will allow you to skip password entry for known hosts. might be really useful in your case

Comment: @Schlomi Also do you happen to have a workflow for reloading the REPL ?   I can kill the vagrant REPL, then reconnect with `cider-connect` but it feels suboptimal.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont.. I do the same as you describe: kill and restart the repl, than reconnects with `cider-connect`